# swift - duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 Simulator only

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, paypal

I'm developing an app that has these sdk's

```
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'
pod 'Stripe'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseUI'
```

Since I started this app, I'm using an actual device (iPhone 5) to test it with no error. But earlier when i tried to run it in the simulator, I'm getting this error. Why does it have an error in simulator but ok on an actual device?

```
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskDeviceData.o)
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskUtility.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskDeviceData.o)
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskUtility.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskDeviceData.o)
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskConfiguration.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskDeviceData.o)
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskConfiguration.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskDeviceData.o)
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskLinkerID.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskDeviceData.o)
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskLinkerID.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskDeviceData.o)
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskComponent.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskDeviceData.o)
    /Users/myname/Desktop/MyApp/Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPRiskComponent.o)
ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried cleaning the build folder and Deleting Derrived Data folder. What do you think is the problem here? Thanks!

Comment: did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I faced same issue, some search led me to this.

The **Note** [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK) says,

> The current version of the PayPal iOS SDK was built using Xcode 7.0+.
>
> If you are still using Xcode 6.2, you may experience link errors
>   (duplicate symbols). If you can't upgrade from Xcode 6.2, please use
>   version 2.10.2 of this SDK.

So I changed the version I am using to 2.11.4 (The one when we started the project was 2.11.4) and it worked.